# Java ArrayList.remove(index) issue

Tags: java, list, arraylist

I've had some issues trying to do this, and I still don't understand why this code doesn't do anything... it removes nothing from my list, just loops around. Some hints?

```
public void compute(){
    String formula ="";
    boolean hasDependencies = false;
    Integer value = 0;

    while(!cellsNotComputed.isEmpty()){
        for(int i=0; i<cellsNotComputed.size(); i++){
            formula = getCell(cellsNotComputed.get(i).getRow(), 
                                cellsNotComputed.get(i).getColumn())
                             .getContent();
            // formulas always begin with = and only contains cell names
            // and + symbols (ex. =A1+A2+A3)
            formula = formula.substring(1);
            String[] dependantCells = formula.split("\\+");

            for (String cellName : dependantCells) {
                for (Cell cell : cellsNotComputed) {
                    if(cell.getName().equals(cellName)){
                        hasDependencies = true;
                    }
                }
                if(!hasDependencies){
                    value = value + getCell(cellName).getValue();
                }
            }

            if(!hasDependencies){
                Cell computedCell = cellsNotComputed.get(i);
                cellsNotComputed.remove(i); // it works but... ** 
                i--;
                computedCell.setValue(value);
                setCell(computedCell.getRow(),
                        computedCell.getColumn(),
                        computedCell);                  
            }

            hasDependencies = false; //** here the element removed is again
                                     // in the list.
            value = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

** Just to clarify, cellsNotComputed is an attribute and is an ArrayList, and it contains all the cells of the table that contains formulas, so they can't be computed until check dependences.

Comment: For the record, cellsNotComputed.clear() would be a quicker way to do the above.

Comment: What type of elements does cellsNotComputed contain?

Comment: You can try `cellsNotComputed.remove(cellsNotComputed.get(i));`

Comment: cellsNotComputed.remove(cellsNotComputed.get(i)) also doesn't remove anything @EpicPandaForce

Comment: Are you sure that line actually runs? If `cellsNotComputed.remove(computedCell);` doesn't work, then you have got bigger problems.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce it runs

Comment: @EpicPandaForce I've checked twice, and I've realized that it actually removes the element but at the end of the if stament where it removes it, the element comes back to the list... I don't understand it

Comment: @Luxy, have you checked the method setCell? Maybe it is messing with the `cellsNotComputed`? Can you create a MCVE?: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve That would allow someone to download and check further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your sample, as stated before, just increments and decrements the counter, it is a strange pattern.

Try something more readable like this one:

```
public void remove(){
    while(!this.cellsNotComputed.isEmpty()) {
        //if you need to do something with the element, extract 0 and do it.
        cellsNotComputed.remove(0);
    }
}
```

Or better, in case you just want to clear:

```
public void remove(){
        cellsNotComputed.clear();
}
```

Comment: even though the i doesn't change (which is something I didn't explain well) the method remove does nothing

Comment: naw, I've removed elements from a list before with `for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) { if(something) { list.remove(i--); } }` and it worked perfectly fine.

Comment: I've edited my code, please have a look

Comment: @Luxy, just as a thought... Might it be that the List you are using is some "special" implementation that maybe has an empty "remove" method? Try printing the Class name: `cellsNotComputed.getClass().getCanonicalName()`... If it's not a standard Java List (like an ArrayList), chances are that the remove Method is not properly implemented...

Comment: @EpicPandaForce, I agree that it should work, but I would encourage to do it in a more readable way. This pattern is just not readable, it causes confusion at first and does exactly the same as the more readable alternatives I listed...

Comment: it gets me java.util.ArrayList

Comment: Well, it seems that there is some other thing going on... I added another comment asking for a MCVE. You should really go that way, just some small sample that easily reproduces the problem and upload it somewhere... I would still look at the setCell method, but I really think that any help with the information that is available right now is pure speculation... For a concrete help, a MCVE is the way to go...

Answer (score 2):

What I could not understand in your code is, if you don't find any match or If you find any cell whose content is not something, this loop is going to be an endless loop.

Consider the following piece of code which I tried for testing.

```
public class Test {

    static class Cell{
        private int id;
        private String content;
        public String getContent() {
            return content;
        }
        public void setContent(String content) {
            this.content = content;
        }
        public Cell(int id, String content) {
            this.id = id;
            this.content = content;
        }
        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Cell [id=" + id + ", content=" + content + "]";
        }
    }

    static private List<Cell> cellsNotComputed;

    public static void main(String[] args){
        cellsNotComputed = new ArrayList<Test.Cell>();
        cellsNotComputed.add(new Cell(1, "Something"));
        //cellsNotComputed.add(new Cell(2, "Hi"));
        System.out.println("Before removing " + cellsNotComputed);
        while(!cellsNotComputed.isEmpty()){
            for(int i=0; i<cellsNotComputed.size(); i++){
                if(cellsNotComputed.get(i).getContent().equals("Something")){
                  System.out.println(cellsNotComputed.remove(i));
                  i--;
                }                   
            }
        }
        System.out.println("After removing " + cellsNotComputed);
    }
```

this will only work if the arrayList has only one cell in it with content exactly as "Something". Please check the content.

I m not sure if this is exactly you want because it will go to infinite loop if :
The list contain any cell whose content is not "Something"

The above code produces

```
Before removing [Cell [id=1, content=Something]]
Cell [id=1, content=Something]
After removing []
```

and terminates

Comment: even though the i doesn't change (which is something I didn't explain well) the method remove does nothing

Comment: I've already tried... nothing happens

Comment: Can you add `cellsNotComputed.remove(i);` inside a sysout statement and tell the results

Comment: es.luxy.spreadsheet.Cell@7852e922

Comment: it just loops with that output

Comment: @Luxy If I m not wrong, you are going through an infinite loop right?

Comment: yes, but it is because it doesn't remove any element of my list, and I don't understand why not

Comment: I've debugged my code, and it does enter into the if condition and calls remove but after that... nothing

Comment: How many items your list has? Please add the complete code now

Comment: in the case I'm debugging, 6

Comment: Thats what I told in my answer, If you have any element with content other than "Something" the loop which you wrote will go endless. Probably u need to rephrase the question and add more details

Comment: I've added my code, but I assume that the essence of the problem was summed up in the shortest version of it

Answer (score 2):

If you wish to empty your list, just call

```
cellsNotComputed.clear ();
```

Comment: this is only a little part of my code, I dont just remove all the elements like this, my code does more things. It checks some things before removes the element, but the thing is that it never does it

Comment: @Luxy How is cellsNotComputed declared?

Comment: ArrayList<Cell> cellsNotComputed;

Comment: it contains Cell elements, which is another class that I have. A Cell has 5 atributtes int row, int column, int value, string content, string name

Comment: I've edited my code, please have a look

Comment: @Luxy Are you sure `cellsNotComputed.remove(i);` actually gets called? Did you run this with a debugger, or add debug prints? Print the size() of the list before and after the call to remove(i).

Comment: yes, sure it calls it I've checked

Comment: I've checked twice, and I've realized that it actually removes the element but at the end of the if stament where it removes it, the element comes back to the list

Answer (score 1):

Your for loop increments `i` every step but inside your loop you just decrement it... So its like `i + 1 - 1 = i`.

Comment: even though the i doesn't change (which is something I didn't explain well) the method remove does nothing

Comment: I've edited my code, please have a look

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove all elements from your list, you can use clear method.

```
cellsNotComputed.clear ();
```

Clear() removes all of the elements from ist. The list will be empty after this call returns.

Answer (score 0):

```
public void remove(){
List<Integer> founds= new ArrayList<Integer>;
    while(!this.cellsNotComputed.isEmpty()){
        for(int i=0; i<this.cellsNotComputed.size(); i++){
            if(cellsNotComputed.get(i).getContent().equals("something")){
              // cellsNotComputed.remove(i);
               founds.add(i);
               //i--;
            }                   
        }
    }
   for(int f: founds){
      cellsNotComputed.remove(f);
   }

}
```

Comment: Can you post more code so that we also see any data? Especially the class cell could be interesting.